# pandas: How to compare value of column with next value

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
  colA  colB
0    A    10
1    B    20
2    C     5
3    D     2
4    F    30
  ....
```

I would like to compare column 1 values to detect two successive decrements. That is, I want to report the index values where I have two successive decrements of column 1. For example, I want to report 'B' because there are two successive rows following B where column 1 values are decremented. I am not sure how to approach this without writing a loop. ( If there is no way to avoid a loop I'd like to know.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use loc for this:

```
desired=frame.loc[(frame["colB"]>=frame["colB"].shift(-1)) &
          (frame["colB"].shift(-1)>=frame["colB"].shift(-2) )]
print(desired)
```

The output will be:

```
   colA colB
1   B   20
```

if you only wish to report the value B:

```
desired=frame["colA"].loc[(frame["colB"]>=frame["colB"].shift(-1)) &
          (frame["colB"].shift(-1)>=frame["colB"].shift(-2) )]
print(desired.values)
```

The output will be:

```
['B']
```

Comment: Elegant! Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what `shift` does there?

Comment: shift gives the series "shifted" up or down by n - so `shift(-1)` gives for each row the value after

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this without using loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'], 'colB':[10, 20, 5, 2, 30]})
>>> df['colC'] = df['colB'].diff(-1)
>>> df
  colA  colB  colC
0    A    10 -10.0
1    B    20  15.0
2    C     5   3.0
3    D     2 -28.0
4    F    30   NaN
```

'colC' is the difference between the consecutive row.

```
>>> df['colD'] = np.where(df['colC'] > 0, 1, 0)
>>> df
  colA  colB  colC  colD
0    A    10 -10.0     0
1    B    20  15.0     1
2    C     5   3.0     1
3    D     2 -28.0     0
4    F    30  -1.0     0
```

In 'colD' we are marking flag where the difference is greater than 0.

```
>>> df1['s'] = df1['colD'].shift(-1)
>>> df1
  colA  colB  colC  colD    s 
0    A    10 -10.0     0  1.0 
1    B    20  15.0     1  1.0 
2    C     5   3.0     1  0.0 
3    D     2 -28.0     0  0.0 
4    F    30  -1.0     0  NaN
```

In column 's' we shift the value of 'colD'.

```
>>> df1['flag'] = np.where((df1['colD'] == 1) & (df1['colD'] == df1['s']), 1, 0)
>>> df1
  colA  colB  colC  colD    s  flag
0    A    10 -10.0     0  1.0     0
1    B    20  15.0     1  1.0     1
2    C     5   3.0     1  0.0     0
3    D     2 -28.0     0  0.0     0
4    F    30  -1.0     0  NaN     0
```

Then 'flag' is required column.

Comment: Nice. It is a generalization of the question asked. Good info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Need a little bit logic here

```
s=df.colB.diff().gt(0) # get the diff 
df.loc[df.groupby(s.cumsum()).colA.transform('count').ge(3)&s,'colA'] # then we using count to see which one is more than 3 items (include the line start to two items decreasing )
Out[45]: 
1    B
Name: colA, dtype: object
```